# A* Pathfinding without diagonal movement

Tags: c++, path-finding

I'm currently trying to implement A* in c++ using: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

However for the first version i decided to not include diagonal movement.

In the summary section in point c where it loops checking the neighbours of the current point:

```
for each neighbour of the current square (above, below, left, right)
    if neighbour on closed list or not walkable {
        continue
    }

    if neighbour not in open list {
        add to open list
        set parent of neighbour to current square
        update F, G, H values
    } else if neighbour is on open list {
        check to see if this path to that square is better, 
        using G cost as the measure. A lower G cost means that this is a better path. 
        If so, change the parent of the square to the current square,
        and recalculate the G and F scores of the square.
    }
```

If i am only allowing 4 direction movement, do i still need to check the g cost to see if the path to that square is better? For example starting at the start point all 4 neighbours of the start point will have the same g.

Comment: If I recall correctly, all the immediate neighbors have the same g cost but if your target is diagonally north west of your location, then the g cost for a path starting from the west or north neighbor would be lower than the g cost if you were to start from the east or south neighbor.

Comment: @NicoSchertler So should i check for the neighbour with the lowest g cost? then set the parent of that square to the current square and re update the values?

Comment: The steps of the A* algorithm don't change depending on how many items are in the set (neighbor of the current cell).  You could even have wormholes/teleporters that have neighbors clear across the map (in addition to the adjacent cells) and A* will still work.

Answer (score 0):

The point of checking for the lower G cost is to set a new path for that square if a better one is eventually found.  You may initially find a path from A to a square C.  But when searching later, you'll find a different path to a neighbor of C.  If C is not in the closed list, the G cost of the new path to C may be lower than the first, so you want to update C with the better G (and thus F) value.

Comment: This is where I'm getting caught up and confused. So while looking at each neighbour I should check to see if that neighbour has a lower g cost than the parent of that node + the distance between neighbour and parent? @aah

Comment: If a neighbor is in the open list but not the closed list, that means it had a previous parent.  So you are calculating the G cost based on the new parent, and comparing it to the G cost of the old parent, and using the smaller of the two.  You don't compare the G cost of the parent to neighbor.

Comment: @PrimateJunkie To clarify, comparing the G cost of the neighbor relative to the old parent to the G cost of the neighbor relative to the new parent.  So if the weight between adjacent squares is W(*,*), and the old parent is P1 and the new is P2, then you are comparing G(P1) + W(P1,C) versus G(P2)+W(P2,C), where C is the neighbor square.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the situation. The basic point is that every edge in the graph has the same weight.

Assume that you are currently at vertex `c` and you analyze neighbor `n`. Then the updated distance for neighbor `n` would be `distance(c) + w`, where `w` is the uniform edge length. Now the question is if `n` can have a larger distance than that via a different path.

Assume the previous parent `p` of `n` that would lead to a longer path. Then, `n` has the distance `distance(p) + w`. In order for that expression to be larger than the updated cost from `c`, the following needs to hold:

```
distance(p) + w > distance(c) + w
distance(p) > distance(c)
```

So `p` would have to be farther away from the start than `c`. If you used Dijkstra's algorithm, this would not be possible because this would mean that `p` would be fixed after `c`. But you use A* and determine the order with the heuristic. Hence, the following two conditions need to hold:

```
distance(p) > distance(c)
distance(p) + heuristic(p) <= distance(c) + heuristic(c)
<=> heuristic(p) <= heuristic(c) - (distance(p) - distance(c))
```

So it comes down to your heuristic. The widely used Manhattan distance heuristic allows this. So if you use this heuristic, you have to check for a lower cost. If your heuristic does not allow the above condition (for example a constant heuristic as in the case of Dijkstra), you don't.